# how to find ffmpeg-php dll for xampp 1.8.1 and php 5.4.7

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp, ffmpeg-php

have problems with installation of ffmpeg-php extension on xampp 1.8.1 and php 5.4.7 on windows. Does anyone have the compiled dll of ffmpeg-php for this versions, i know how to install the extension but i can't find the correct dlls for my php version. Any help will be appreciated.